# Javascript: Add 30 days to date?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a `dateObject` pulled from my database: `2021-01-02T15:12:05.000Z`. I'd like to add 30 days to that date so that the end date is: `2021-02-01T15:12:05.000Z`. How would I get this to work?

Reading various posts, I've tried:

```
let storePlanStartDate = dateObject;

storePlanStartDate.setDate(storePlanStartDate.getDate() + 30)

//returns: 1614784325000
```

I think the return value: `1614784325000` may be what I'm looking for. However, I'm struggling to convert it back to the same format as the original database return so that I can save the updated date.

Comment: `new Date(1614784325000).toISOString()` gives `'2021-03-03T15:12:05.000Z'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is just the default representation of a date - dates are stored as number of milliseconds since datum.

If you format the value as an ISO string (for example) you'll see it actually has the value you expected

```js
let storePlanStartDate = new Date("2021-01-02T15:12:05.000Z");

storePlanStartDate.setDate(storePlanStartDate.getDate() + 30)

console.log(storePlanStartDate.toISOString());
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!

Comment: This absolutely needs to be top answer for adding 30 days to current date javascript, was scrolling through 4 other articles looking for an explanation on how to convert that returned //returns: 1614784325000 number back into ISOString(). figures it would be a simple fix...